# scripting buildroot configuration file

Tags: buildroot

I am trying to switch between external and internal build via some export variable in a script. I am able to do this partially meaning for bool values but for those which take in strings how to tell buildroot to continue with default value and not prompt for values to the user.

For e.g., `BR2_TOOLCHAIN_EXTERNAL_STRIP=y` works fine, as it takes in bool value, but `BR2_TOOLCHAIN_EXTERNAL_PATH` prompts for a value, even though default is set to the correct path.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to switch easily between internal and external toolchain builds, then I would suggest creating fragments of defconfig files:

- One defining the internal toolchain configuration
- One defining the external toolchain configuration
- One defining the common options

And then, you just to :

```
cat internal-toolchain.config common.config > configs/myown_defconfig
make myown_defconfig
```

and there you are. And similarly with `external-toolchain.config`.